# In Git, how can I determine the version (hash) of a clone source?

Tags: git

I have been handed an old pc with a cloned repository on it. git status shows the local repo up to date with the remote repo on a server here. git log -10 shows the most recent commits are from almost a year ago. How can I determine the version of the clone source that the local clone target was cloned from?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking for. A *commit* is uniquely identified by its hash; the same commit has the same hash in every copy of a repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version that a repo was cloned from is (by default) stored in the `origin` remote tracking branches. You can use the following command to get all the branch heads and commit ids:

```
git branch -a -v
```

It sounds like you are looking for `remotes/origin/master` in that list.

Comment: Is that affected if I do `git fetch` ?

Comment: @zatta: Yes, `git fetch` updates the remote tracking branches for the remote (`origin` by default).